# Need To Print Backslash When Preparing mysql statement

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, escaping

I have a file that needs to be converted into a mysql insert statement and it's in the following format:

```
1
'Jan'
'Jame'
'O\'Leary'
'Bill'
''
NULL
1
'Eddie'
'Eddie'
'Unknown'
NULL
NULL
'John'
NULL
'Joseph'
```

I'm trying to use the following code in order to prepare the statements:

```
COUNTER=1;
echo "insert into database.table values " > full_statements.sql

while read LINE
do
    # There are 16 fields of information per insert statement.
    MODULUS=$(( $COUNTER % 16 ))
    # First piece of information needs to be in format "(value"
    if [ "$COUNTER" -eq 1 ]; then
        printf "("$LINE >> full_statements.sql
    # Last piece of information needs to be in format ",value),"        
    elif [ "$MODULUS" -eq 0 ]; then
        printf ","$LINE")," >> full_statements.sql
    # Interior pieces of information need to be in format ",value"
    else
        printf ","$LINE >> full_statements.sql
    fi

    # If we have a complete insert statement, reset the COUNTER.
    if [ "$COUNTER" -eq 16 ]; then
        COUNTER=1
    else
        ((COUNTER++))
    fi
done < binfile.new
```

Unfortunately my result is the following:

```
insert into database.table values
(1,'Jan','Jame','O'Leary','Bill','',NULL,1,'Eddie','Eddie','Unknown',NULL,NULL,'John',NULL,'Joseph');
```

**Expected Output:**

```
 insert into database.table values
    (1,'Jan','Jame','O\'Leary','Bill','',NULL,1,'Eddie','Eddie','Unknown',NULL,NULL,'John',NULL,'Joseph');
```

The backslash that I used to escape the quote in O'Leary's name will not print. I am pulling my hair out trying to get this "\" included in the output but haven't been able to find an answer.

Help! :-)

Comment: not an answer, but do read this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Comment: try `echo -e "insert into database.table values \n ( $(awk -vORS="," '{$1=$1}1' INPUTFILE) );" |sed 's/\(.*\),/\1/'`

Comment: also, add expected output so that others can compare their solutions...

Comment: PS, I'm not sure where that goes in the code -- can you elaborate please with a code segment?

Comment: Use `printf` properly: `printf '(%s' "$LINE"` make go a long way to fixing your problems.

Answer (score 1):

In awk. Using modulo 16 to recognize record change (ie. supports more than 16 lines in a file) and ternary operator to insert stuff before and after stuff:

```
$ cat program.awk 
{
    printf "%s%s%s",(NR%16==1?"INSERT INTO DATABASE VALUES (":""),$0,(NR%16?",":");"ORS)
}
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -f program.awk file
INSERT INTO DATABASE VALUES (1,'Jan','Jame','O\'Leary','Bill','',NULL,1,'Eddie','Eddie','Unknown',NULL,NULL,'John',NULL,'Joseph');
```

Answer (score 0):

From `help read`:

> ```
>  -r       do not allow backslashes to escape any characters
> ```

```
$ read foo <<< '12\3'
$ echo "$foo"
123
$ read -r foo <<< '12\3'
$ echo "$foo"
12\3
```

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a task for `pr`

Suppose input file contains 5 lines and you want to group by 2 elements each:

```
$ seq 5 | pr -2ats, | sed 's/.*/\t(&);/'
    (1,2);
    (3,4);
    (5);
```

- `seq 5` sample input with 5 lines
- `pr -2ats,` print max of 2 fields separated by `,`
- `sed 's/.*/\t(&)/'` post process the `pr` output to add `()` around the text, add `;` at end of line and a `tab` in front of line

So, finally for your use case, it would be something like this:

```
$ ( echo 'insert into database.table values' ; pr -16ats, binfile.new | sed 's/.*/\t(&);/' ) > full_statements.sql
```

Comment: that alerts to unexpected token 'echo'

Comment: okay, seems like you added `$` at the beginning of the command as well.. that is meant to indicate command prompt and not part of actual command :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be a little simpler. Aside from the refactoring, the actual fix is to use the `-r` option with `read` to prevent backslashes in the input from being interpreted. Using `IFS=` is good practice to ensure the each line is read verbatim, without stripping any leading or trailing whitespace.

```
# It's easier to just hard-code the 16 %s rather than build it dynamically.
fmt="insert into database.table values (
%s, %s, %s, %s,
%s, %s, %s, %s,
%s, %s, %s, %s,
%s, %s, %s, %s)\n"

# Read 16 lines, putting each line in a global array
# Return 1 if any read fails
read16 () {
    values=()
    for ((i=0; i<16; i++)); do
        IFS= read -r line || return 1
        values+=("$line")
    done
}

declare -a values
while read16; do
  printf "$fmt" "${values[@]}"
done < binfile.new > full_statements.sql
```

Note that if you put the single quotes in the format string:

```
fmt="insert ... ('%s', '%s', ...)\n"
```

then you don't need to include them in the data file:

```
1
Jan
Jame
O'Leary
Bill
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' -v ORS=');\n' -v m=16 '{n=(NR-1)%m+1; f[n]=$0} n==m{printf "insert blah\n   ("; for (i=1;i<=m;i++) printf "%s%s", f[i], (i<m ? OFS : ORS)}' file
insert blah
   (1,'Jan','Jame','O\'Leary','Bill','',NULL,1,'Eddie','Eddie','Unknown',NULL,NULL,'John',NULL,'Joseph');
```